# juju-local and cgroup-lite

Tags: 12.04, juju

Im trying to configure juju-local on my virtual-box machine to test some environments, learn, play and then make some desition to deploy to my cloud.

I follow the docs on juju page (https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html, https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-local.html) but always get this error on any service:

status: "hook failed: install"

i do some research and use juju-debug hooks and find that the install error was on cgroup-lite.

Can anybody helpme? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting [Bug #1247299](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1247299). I think you are stuck until this is fixed in Juju 1.1.17

Comment: My fault - sorry.  I have submitted a patch and hopefully we'll be able to roll 1.16.3 soon.